# Interpolation lambda hard to understand

Tags: python, lambda, geometry, interpolation

`poly1` and `poly2` are both lists containing coordinates (x,y).

Now this function is pre-implemented, which I find hard to understand:

```
def interpolate():
    # This function returns a list of tuples (x, y).
    return map(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]), poly_1,
               [(time * x[0], time * x[1]) for x in map(lambda p, q: (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1]), poly_1, poly_2)])
```

But can you actually explain what happens in `interpolate`?

All I can extract from this is (as far as the lambdas go)

```
def func_a(a, b):
    return (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1])
```

and

```
def func_b(p, q):
    return (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1]), poly_1, poly_2)
```

But all that mapping is confusing to me.

Comment: If you look up `map()` and `lambda` you can try and write this out in several longer form `def` functions

Comment: it is doing some calculations over the 2 coordinates lists.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Could you please do that?

Comment: is it me or the three maps/loops could be reduced to one? (confused too)

Answer (score 2):

map simply apply a function to every element in one or more arrays

Lets take a look:

```
return map(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]), poly_1,
           [(time * x[0], time * x[1]) for x in map(lambda p, q: (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1]), poly_1, poly_2)])
```

Its a `map` function that takes 3 arguments:

1. `lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1])` can be translated as

`def foo(a,b) : return (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1])`

You will apply it on next two lists

2. The first list poly_1
3. The second list `[(time * x[0], time * x[1]) for x in map(lambda p, q: (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1]), poly_1, poly_2)]`:

First its a list of tuples with two arguments `time * x[0], time * x[1]`

"x" is taken from the list that return from `map(lambda p, q: (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1]), poly_1, poly_2)`

Lets translate it:

1. map applies the lambda function to every element of poly_1 and poly_2
2. `lambda p, q: (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1])` equals to

`def foo2(p,q) : return (q[0] - p[0], q[1] - p[1])`

Comment: Coud you please reformat, I think the formatting is a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

side note:

```
def interpolate(poly_1, poly_2):
    return map(lambda p, q: (p[0] + t*(q[0]-p[0]), p[1] + t*(q[1]-p[1])), poly_1, poly_2)
```

does the same job. way faster